# Jquery ajax complete not getting custom reponse header?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pass a custom response header to notify my javascript the user has timed out. It works good expect when it comes to using it with jquery u.i dialogs.

I have this

```
$.ajaxSetup
({
    complete: function (event, xhr, options)
    {

        if (event.getResponseHeader('X-LOGON') === 'LogOn')
        {

            window.location.href = "redirect to signin";
        }
    }

});
```

So this should run after every jquery ajax request and it does.

Now I have something like this for my dialog

```
  $.manageAjax.add('NonCachedAjaxRequests',
    {
        type: "GET",
        url: 'ajaxRequestPath',
        success: function (result)
        {
            $('#Dialog').html(result).dialog(
            {
                width: 580,
                height: 410,
                resizable: false,
                modal: true,
                buttons:
                {
                    Cancel: function ()
                    {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    },
                    'Create': function ()
                    {
                        // create;   
                    }
                },
                close: function ()
                {
                    //destroy
                }
            });


        }
    });

    return false;

});
```

I am using something called ajax manager http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/ajaxManager/ this just helps with stopping double clicks and stuff like that and uses all the same methods that $.ajax would use.

So now when I look at the request coming back to populate the above dialog box I see this in firebug

```
Response Headersview source
Server  ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
Date    Fri, 02 Jul 2010 22:12:36 GMT
X-AspNet-Version    4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version 2.0
X-LOGON LogOn
Cache-Control   private
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length  6468
Connection  Close
```

Notice how it says "X-LOGON" but when it comes to my ajaxSetup and gets to

```
if (event.getResponseHeader('X-LOGON') === 'LogOn')
```

it always says it is null but as you can clearly see firebug is saying otherwise. I don't understand whats is going on.

**Edit**

Ok it seems to be a problem with ajax manager. I really want to keep using it or something comparable as it really helps out with stopping duplicate requests.

What I found out is that it does not like global ajaxSetups I don't know why it just does not like them. I started to try to use status codes instead so I been playing around with "403" and found this.

if an ajax request 403's out and your using ajaxSetup with complete and ajaxmanager it will still try to go into the success message one.

If you put an ajax complete before the success one(it does not work if complete is after success) and it comes back with 403 then ajax manager has no problem acting on it and hitting the complete.

So I am not sure what to do. I want to use ajaxmanager or something like it and I want to use ajaxSetup.

So I don't know if I can have both at this moment though.

**Edit 2**

When I use status codes and ajaxSetup with ajax manager I get this error

> error: status: 403 | URL:
>   /MyURL
>   http://localhost:3086/Plugins/AjaxManager/Source/jquery.ajaxmanager.js
>   Line 44

```
 error: function(ahr, status){
36 var opts = this;
37 if(status && status.indexOf('error') != -1){
38 setTimeout(function(){
39 var errStr = status +': ';
40 if(ahr.status){
41 errStr += 'status: '+ ahr.status +' | ';
42 }
43 errStr += 'URL: '+ opts.url;
44 throw new Error(errStr);
45 }, 1);
46 }
47 },
```

so I don't know if this is another reason why I am getting an error.

Edit 4

Seems like I been using a version that apparently is not compatable for version 1.4(not sure why it worked)

Anyways I am using 3.0 now it still does not work but it has some new options that I would like to try but have no clue how to use them.

http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/ajaxManager3/

If you look at the events/callbacks it's got some global complete so maybe that might be what I need. Have no clue how to run it though.

Comment: have you tried doing the exact same thing without manageAjax to rule out any possible issues with that plug in? (I know it shouldn't cause an issue but crazier things have happened)

Comment: What if you use getAllResponseHeaders? Does that show the X-LOGON header?

Comment: Lines like `$.ajaxSetup \n ({` make me uncomfortable due to JavaScript's automagic semicolon insertion (which may or may not apply in this case).

Comment: @Roberto I think your right it seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the source code of manageAjax is available here:
http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/ajaxManager/jquery.ajaxmanager.js

The global jquery 'complete' function is sent via those line :

```
if (opts.global) {
    $.event.trigger("ajaxComplete", args);
}
```

This creates a new Event object on the fly so it blanks out any data you may have available on the original event.

I might be wrong, but after reading the code quickly, the headers are lost early in manageAjax and I am not sure you can do what you want while using this library until the library gets patched to allow this.

So Roberto's comment seems like a good advice : try it without manageAjax and it will most probably work

I hope this will help you,

Jerome Wagner

Comment: Hmm I think your right. It is the ajax manager. I don't know if this plugin is being even developed anymore but it solves some of my other problems so unless there is another one out there I want to continue to use it. I tried using just .ajax and it works just fine but I would not know how to even begin to fix the problem with ajax manager. What I found too is it ajaxmanager does not like global ajax setups. If I put complete in my ajax one instead of global it works but for some reason it has to go before success otherwise it does not work. So I am not sure what to do now.

Comment: I would prefer to use the global setup too as I have lots of ajax requests and it sucks to put the same thing in each one.