# JQuery AjaxComplete Method Stripping Out Custom Headers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to follow option #3 in the solution at this SO post: [A controller action which returns a partial view inserts the logon page when authorization fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198679/a-controller-action-which-returns-a-partial-view-inserts-the-logon-page-when-aut)

I'm running into a problem reading my custom header in the ajaxComplete method in jquery.

I have confirmed in fiddler and in chrome's debug tools that the custom header is in fact being sent back and received by the browser...

Response Headers (in Fiddler):

```
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
Date: Sun, 15 Jan 2012 04:00:13 GMT
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 3.0
Unauthorized: 1
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 0
Connection: Close
```

Response Headers (as received by Chrome):

```
Cache-Control:private
Connection:Close
Content-Length:0
Date:Sun, 15 Jan 2012 04:12:13 GMT
Server:ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
Unauthorized:1
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version:3.0
```

Response Headers (as found from calling "getAllResponseHeaders()" on the xmlHttpRequest variable passed into ajaxComplete):

```
Date: Sun, 15 Jan 2012 04:42:21 GMT
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Connection: Close
Content-Length: 65
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 3.0
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: private
```

Interestingly, the function that is called upon the return of the original ajax request (as initiated by jquery) does receive the Unauthorized header.

Does anyone know what's going on here and what I can do to solve this issue?

Here's my "ajaxComplete" javascript code

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, request, settings) {
        alert(request.getResponseHeader('Unauthorized'));
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vucetica's initial response got me thinking and I spent the last hour looking through jquery's code. I have my custom header coming back now. It looks like the trouble stemmed from an unhandled exception in my code within the success callback of the original ajax request.

Definitely something I should fix, but it seems odd that jquery would allow itself to be susceptible to that in a way that it fails silently and only affecting the custom headers. This unexpected behavior really led me in the wrong direction initially.

Anyway, thanks for your help everyone.

For completeness sake, here is my code before and after.

Before (no custom headers received in the ajaxComplete method)

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Game/GetPlay/27?roundId=" + that.gameState.RoundToDisplay,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: {},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (play, request, settings) {
        that.play = play;
        that.startGame();
    },
    error: null,
    cache: false
});
```

After (working)

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Game/GetPlay/27?roundId=" + that.gameState.RoundToDisplay,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: {},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (play, request, settings) {
        that.play = play;
        try {
            that.startGame();
        } catch(err){

        }
    },
    error: null,
    cache: false
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169419/jquery-ajax-complete-not-getting-custom-reponse-header). It might be helpful if you are using the same plugin (ajaxmanager) on your page. If not, check your other plugins.

Comment: I did see that SO post beforehand. I am not using Ajax Manager. I do have other JS libraries loaded, I will check to see if any of them use Ajax Manager or are tying in to ajaxComplete themselves but at this point it's not a likelihood IMO.

Comment: Confirmed, no reference to ajaxmanager, "ajax manager", ajaxcomplete or ajaxsuccess anywhere other than the code I mentioned in my original post and within jquery itself.

Comment: Do you know where did "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" came from? You have it in getAllResponseHeaders but not in chrome inspect. Also, can you post results of getAllResponseHeaders of your original ajax call?